# How to pass system property in vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm running a vertx module using the following command.

> vertx runmod myModule -Dconfig.location=myConfigLocation

In my code I'm using the following

> String configLocation = System.getProperty("config.location");

But I'm getting null for configLocation. Anybody know whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to do this myself.
I found from the vertx script that JAVA_OPT and VERTX_OPT can be filled out with extra options to pass to the JVM such as defines and vert.x based defines. If you are running this as a service and would like a standard set to be passed to all vert.x calls there is a JVM_OPT variable in the vertx script to include things like specific GC or system based information like -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit.

Comment: sorry that is the JAVA_OPT system variable and VERTX_OPT system variable. You can set these in linux via an export JAVA_OPT="-Dxxxxxxx=yyyy" ect.